# VSCode Build/Release Process

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was looking into the VSCode build process and it looks like the `mixinProduct` function from `gulp.vscode.js` was removed.  I saw a mention to a distro repo and was curious how you all build and release VSCode now.  In the past you would pull in `product.json` in `gulp.vscode.js` by the use of an environment variable `PRODUCT_JSON_FILE`.

It looks like things have been moved into a private repo for a gulp task called `mixin` that pulls in `product.json` config files for different qualities and different releases types.  If you could shed some light into how this works that would be awesome.

Also what are you using for the CI engine to build the `insider` releases?

Answer (score 1):

The specifics of how VS Code handles release are not public.

At a high level, the released "VS Code Build" is exactly the same code as from the public github repo, just with a few different assets and configuration files included. [This comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60#issuecomment-161792005) provides a bit more detail